# In Fedora 31 how do I set permissions for nginx running in a Podman container?

Tags: permissions, fedora, selinux, podman, slim-4

I am trying to set up a local dev LEMP stack for a Slim-4 project using podman-compose. So far I have containers for PHP and Nginx. Nginx runs but gives a 500 error on trying to access the log directory - permission denied. This directory is outside of the public directory that is served by nginx.

I have selinux set to permissive to eliminate its issues.
I have used podman unshare to set ownership to the container's Nginx UID:GID.
I tried the setup with only a simple index file - the file is served with no issues. So, nginx/podman has access to the nginx configuration file on the host. The issue must be with write permissions.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

# Services
services:

# Nginx Service
nginx:
  image: nginx:1.17
  ports:
    - 8090:80
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/php:z
    - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
  depends_on:
    - php

# PHP Service
php:
  image: php:7.4-fpm
  working_dir: /var/www/php
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/php
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I incorrectly assumed I needed to set permissions to allow Nginx to have access.
Instead I needed to grant the group www-data access permissions. 
**How I did it:**
log into the running Nginx container `podman exec -it [container ID] bash` 
find the www-data GID (Group ID) - from the container command line, `cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data` 
note the GID (in the result you will see something like `...x:33:33...` 33:33 is the user:group) 
exit the container cli with `exit` 
in your development/host cli, at the root of your project, run `podman unshare chown -R 0:[the www-data GID you found above] .`  (don't miss the '.') 
**Explanation:**
`podman unshare` puts you in a modified userspace that matches the container 
`chown` changes ownership 
`-R` means recursive 
the number to the left of the ':' is the UID (User ID), the number to the right is the GID 
the '.' is the current directory.

I hope this helps someone. I spent hours learning the above.

Comment: This and https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rootless-podman-makes-sense helped me. Tnx. Instead `podman unshare chown -R 0:33.` i had to use `podman unshare chown -R 33:33.` for Nginx to handle `uploads` directory.